# Determining condition of a checkbox in an event handler

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some checkboxes and I have assigned all of them to one event handler.

How can I find out if sender is checked or unchecked?

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? WPF? What event handler?

Comment: @Adel - What's that got to do with the question?

Comment: @Oded, hmm true. OK this page then: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows Forms all events have a sender variable.

```
if(((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
```

Should do.

Comment: thanks, it needs one another pair of () though. I will check this as answer after 5m because of limitation :)

Answer (score 1):

convert the sender argument to checkbox and check the checked property.

```
(sender as CheckBox).Checked
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `Checked` property indicates if the checkbox is currently checked or not.

`sender` in the following code is the first parameter of the event:

```
var checkbox = (CheckBox) sender;
if (checkbox.Checked)
{
    // Checkbox seems to be checked
}
```

Have a look at the documentation for the [checkbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.aspx).